# Как переносить ячейки qgridlayout в зависимости от ширины окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, grid, layout

Есть ли такой метод, который будет переносить ячейки QGridLayout в зависимости от ширины окна?

Comment: О каких ячейках вы говорите?  Куда вы из хотите переносить? Покажите пример который у вас есть и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: вам придется контролировать размер окна и в случае необходимости ручками изменять компоновку